# Java FXML - NetBeans - Delete from Table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, javafx, netbeans

I get the following error when I attempt to delete a row from `TableView`:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[value: 3]' at line 1
```

What I want: Once a row from `TableView` is selected, I want to delete it from database.

```java
@FXML
void delete(ActionEvent event) {
    try {

        int pos;
        pos = (int) tabelCustomers.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        Customers c;
        c = tabelCustomers.getItems().get(pos);
        SimpleIntegerProperty idc = c.idc;
        String query;
        query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.idc = " + idc;

        try (Statement stm = cnx.createStatement()) {
            stm.executeUpdate(query);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(CustomersTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I have tried a lot of possible solutions, nothing works.
Basically, when a user clicks on the row in a table and then clicks on the "remove" button, that row should be deleted from table and DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
SimpleIntegerProperty idc = c.idc;
String query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.idc = " + idc;
```

When an `Object` (that is not a `String`) is used in string concatenation it is automatically converted into a `String` by calling `toString()` on it. The string representation of `SimpleIntegerProperty` is not simply its value, which means your query ends up looking something like:

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.idc = IntegerProperty [bean: <some_instance>, name: idc, value: 42]
```

Which is obviously not valid SQL. You need to extract the value of the property and use that as part of the query. However, you should not use string concatenation when creating SQL queries in the first place. You should instead be using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with parameters. For example:

```java
String query = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.idc = ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement(query)) {
  ps.setInt(1, idc.get());
  ps.executeUpdate();
}
```